# Make progressbar run for a time period I specify

Tags: timer, progress-bar

Let's say I want a progress bar to run for 2 minutes according to an if statement, then in another I want it to restart and run for 1 minutes. How do I do that? I've been trying with the countdowntimer but I keep messing up.

```
         private void startTimer() {
            millisInFuture = mTimeLeftInMillis;
            mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
                    updateCountDownText();
                    final long millisPassed = millisInFuture - mTimeLeftInMillis;
                    progress = (int) (millisPassed * 100 / millisInFuture);
                    pb.setProgress(progress);
                    pb2.setProgress(0);
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    //Key: 60 sec
                    if (millisInFuture == 480000) {
                        if (millisPassed <= 60000 || (millisPassed > 180000 && millisPassed <= 240000) || (millisPassed > 300000 && millisPassed <= 360000 || (millisPassed > 420000 && millisPassed <= 480000))) {
                            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(tool1mode1.this, R.anim.fade_in);
                            stepupimage.setAnimation(animation);
                           /////HERE
                        } else if ((millisPassed > 60000 && millisPassed <= 180000) || (millisPassed > 240000 && millisPassed <= 300000) || (millisPassed > 360000 && millisPassed <= 420000)) {
                            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(tool1mode1.this, R.anim.fade_in);
                            stepdownimage.setAnimation(animation);
                           /////HERE
                        }
                    }
```

the parts I commented as "HERE" are where I want the progress bar "pb2" to run for 1 minute and 2 minutes respectively.

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Comment: May I ask what is wrong with the tags?

Comment: The [android-studio] tag is for questions about the IDE itself, **not** for general programming questions.

Comment: And just "android"? I mean that's what I wrote.